# compiling class files for Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

after having run the default wordcount example in Hadoop successfully, I created a new java file by copying the content of the wordcount example. I modified the code a little bit. Now I want to compile the new java file, create *.jar file. I do not have eclipse, as this seems to be a headache. So plain java code in vim, without any file structure as eclipse would generally create.

My question is: 
given I have a java file in a particular folder, how can I compile it and run it? All the tutorials I have seen on the internet don't really show these steps. What if I have some libraries used in my java program?

I really hope someone gives a good insight to me.
Thx!

Comment: _I do not have eclipse, as this seems to be a headache_ - In my opinion, using the command line and getting everything right is more of a headache. If you're starting out, i suggest you also look into some build tools like Apache Ant or Maven that will still allow you to use the command line, but abstract you away from the details of javac and all it's flags

Comment: Only If I could find some helpful tutorials for building the eclipe plugin. I am using Eclipse Indigo and the hadoop version I am using is 1.0.2. Many people posted that the tutorials available on the internet don't work with these versions.

Comment: You don't need the hadoop plugin to compile code in eclipse - the plugin is just a nice UI view of HDFS andjob tracker

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure all dependencies(Hadoop jars and jars in $HADOOP_HOME/lib) are in the **CLASS_PATH**. One can use Hadoop CLI command "**bin/hadoop classpath**(I use version 0.22.0)" to get all dependencies. Then, use javac to compile your source code. I also suggest you look into some build tools like **Ant** or **Maven**.